# Accidentally closed view in Xcode 4.1?

Tags: xcode, view

While using the interface builder in Xcode 4.1, I clicked delete twice by accident and my view in the objects window has disappeared.

Is there any way to get it back? I can't seem to find it in the project folder and I'm not using source control.

Comment: Next time, think about using SVN or Git...

Comment: It looks like I may have Git enabled. Is is possible, and if so, is there a quick way to explain how to obtain my lost view from in there?

Comment: Depends on if you've committed to Git before you deleted your view. If you have, go into the Version Editor. There's too much to explain in an SO Comment; check the docs or use Google. If you haven't, check Time Machine (backups are a really nice idea). ...In the end, though, if you can't find it, just recreate the view. IB only lets you do so much, and if you haven't lost any code, then it shouldn't be too hard to recreate it. Certainly not an hour or two of looking around for it. And an older version might have your view, but lost other changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had a lot in that view, but I guess I can redo it in about an hour or two. Ughhhh.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>⌘</kbd> - <kbd>Z</kbd> to undo the previous action(s). Or, under the options menu at the top, manually select "Undo".

Alternately, if you're desperate, exit IB without saving. You'll lose all changes since the last save, but if that includes a major screw-up, it may well be worth it.

If you have already exited IB, then you're pretty much screwed unless you have a back up somewhere.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried right away that and nothing happened. I noticed that I do have source control enabled, but I can't figure out where to find the view in there.

Comment: The IB is a different application from Xcode. Opening a xib file opens the IB application and then renders the file in that application. If you're on a Max, you can use cmd-tab to move between the two. Make sure you "undo" in IB, not in Xcode.

Comment: Err...IB has been integrated into Xcode since 4.0. @OP—Did you quit Xcode in the middle? That would clear the undos. @PengOne, I think the default setting in Xcode 4 now is to save before quitting, without prompting. At least, I'm not finding an option for it in the beta anymore (was there in 4.0).

Comment: @Inspire48: I have yet to upgrade. Thanks for that clarification.

Comment: I didn't quit, but somehow clicked from the view to my .h file and back. It looks like undo might be cleared when you go from one to another.

Comment: No, it's not; I had just used this functionality about an hour ago, so I'm certain. Something must have happened in between. You're not low on RAM when Xcode is running, are you? Xcode might be purging undos to save RAM...